# How can I add new language support in the Overleaf LaTeX editor?

Tags: latex, overleaf, georgian

I'm trying to add Georgian text support in **Overleaf** **LaTeX** editor but it shows me empty space where the **Georgian** text is supposed to be. How Georgian text looks: `ეს არის ქართული ტექსტი.`

[image]

I tried adding `\usepackage[georgian]{babel}` in `background.tex` as well as in the main file A.K.A. `David_Shainidze_CV_GEO.tex`, but still facing the same issue.

I've also tried selecting different supported compilers on the platform but nothing has changed. Ex: Tried `LuaLaTeX` and `XeLaTeX`:
[image]

Here's the project structure:

[image]

- [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```latex
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{../components/commonheader}

\begin{document}

ეს არის ქართული ტექსტი

\end{document}
```

- The entire source code of the project:
  https://github.com/dsha256/modular-latex-resume

Please, don't hesitate to ask if you need some additional details for giving a shot to my issue.

Thanks in advance! Appreciate any type of interaction and willingness to help me <3.14

Comment: You'll need to use a font which actually does have the characters from your language. Please add a [mre] to your question so we can see which font you currently use.

Comment: Will the full source code make sense? https://github.com/dsha256/modular-latex-resume
@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre]. This will ensure that your questions remains useful for future users with the same problem even in case your link stops working.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the suggestion. I did it. I'd be happy if there will be other suggestions to improve the question. Love to do at least this contribution for the community.
@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to use a font which includes the characters of your language, e.g.

---

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{../components/commonheader}

\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

ეს არის ქართული ტექსტი

\end{document}
```

[image]

- You also must not use `&` in normal text. You will see an error about this in the log file. You have to escape it with `... Frontend team (2 Engineers) \& the Backend team ...`
- Don't try to compile your document with xelatex. You load packages which exclusively work with lualatex

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does what I needed exactly.

Regarding `&` - If you found this char in the source without `\\`, it should be a typo, since the Overleaf editor simply doesn't show that in the compiled file.